# Getting link text within a div

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have an href that I'd like to pull text from. Unfortunately I don't have access to to code, and the limited code I have to work with is the following:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <h1 class="myClass">
    <a href="link">TEXT</a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

I'd prefer using JavaScript to obtain this information. What would be the best way to reference 'TEXT'? I've tried a couple methods using `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`, but each have proven unsuccessful. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var text = document.getElementById('myDiv')
                   .getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
alert(text);​ // TEXT
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/LtUr3/)

If you can use jQuery...:

```
var text = $('#myDiv .myClass a').text();
```

Comment: this is probably the most reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery?

It would be

```
$(".myClass a").text();
```

Im not sure in plain javascript. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    console.log('Link ' + i + ' text: ' + links[i].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't modify the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/9rXaS/

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Elements by class name doesn't work in old IE, afaik. Of course, who uses that, but just for reference - shouldn't be used for live code.